# Exchange 2013 - Mailbox for a store

Tags: exchange, email-server, exchange-2013, mailbox

At work we are currently checking to create a generic mailbox for every store of the company, like a branch mailbox. However, each store has multiple users (POS users and managers) and we need to give everyone the access, even the users who don't have a mailbox on their own.

For example, the store in Kingston has 3 managers (real persons) and 5 POS users (branch.kg01 - branch.kg05). We want to create a email **kingston@ourcompany.com** that each one of them will be able to access via Outlook.

I tried creating a mailbox for one the POS users, then give the others a delegate access but since the other POS users don't have an existing mailbox, we can't give them access.

Is there a way in Exchange we can create a sort of Shared Mailbox without using delegates?

EDIT: I tried using a Shared Mailbox, but it still needs a base mailbox to be added to. The managers have their own email, but not the POS users.

Comment: Yes. There is an object type called "Shared Mailbox" that is meant to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Ditto. A shared mailbox is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, no. The shared mailbox needs to be added to a user who has a mailbox already. It's like a secondary mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

A shared mailbox is what you want - despite what you have said.

Create the mailbox in the usual way, creating the underlying AD Account.
Then change the mailbox to type shared, which will disable the underlying AD account.

Using ADUC, give the other users the permissions required (Send as and Receive As).

Then when you are setting up Outlook, you need to do a manual configuration and enter the email address of the shared mailbox. Outlook will find it and provide access using the credentials of the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up creating a normal user mailbox for each store, with a unknown password and we created an automated VBS script that creates an autologin form in HTML for OWA. The script is executed via GPO on logon.

This way, each store has access to their own mailbox via the shortcut link.